# oAuth request token issue Codeigniter/Magento2

Tags: php, codeigniter, magento, oauth

Been going around in circles with this and not getting a definitive answer... The error I am facing is:

`oauth_problem=Cannot+create+request+token+because+consumer+token+is+not+a+verifier+token`

Everything is correctly set with regards to my oAuth request header and sending to magento path `/oauth/token/request`. I have, even though the documentation says it doesn't require it (but for testing) added the verifier string to the request...

Pasting the code in here would make for a very long post and the code is working fine albeit it seems something is missing? If I use the verifier string in the consumer key it gives me the following error instead:

`oauth_problem=Consumer+key+is+not+the+correct+length`

Does anyone have any nuggets of information that the following links are missing that's tripping me up?

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/webapi/integration.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html#pre-auth-token

I have found this on github, some people have seemed to work it out but not forthcoming with the details of how? [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2540)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you already have a request token created in Magento DB table `oauth_token` (if you're like me and developing an app and raising requests over and over to test), clear this table of its entries (request and verify) before retrying and this error won't appear.

**2020 UPDATE:**
This answer [is still valid](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2540#issuecomment-230092278). Sometimes you may need to clear the Magento cache also after clearing the `oauth_token` table entries.

Comment: It did back in 2016, and did for others too when I posted it to the GitHub issue
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2540#issuecomment-230092278

Comment: Yeah, it later worked for me too, I also had to clear Magento cache. I didn't know it was you that posted it on Github. Thank you very much for your answer.